# do boost::asio async write need a mutex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to understand the boost::asio but have some problems with it. In [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp), *please correct me if I'm wrong.*

1. The message is given by reference to the write() method and by value to do_write(). So I think this is ok, even though the do_write is done by io_service.post, the boost::bind is binding the message by value.
2. But why is there no mutex for the **write_msgs_** queue, since std::deque might move around or copy its elements, if needed and io_service::run has it's own thread, it is not ensured the data is consistent.
3. Is it not better to do it by pointer. If the messages are to long they have always to be copied by value. But with new and delete they will be created before and deleted after sending. Then I would do the send like so

### code

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
      boost::asio::buffer(*write_msgs_.front().data(),
        write_msgs_.front().length()),
      boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1) Is correct and the reason why 2) works.

You don't need a mutex here because the synchronization between the main and the client handler thread is done via the `io_service::post` method. `post` doesn't actually execute anything but adds a callback(the bound method) to the callback handlers which are the threads which execute `io_service::run` and such std::deque is only accessed by the **one** thread that runs `io_service::run`.

#### 3) This is a question of thread-safety, exception-safety and ownership.

Concerning thread-safety you need to be 100% sure that after you called `write` only one thread will access the string pointed to by your pointer.
Ownership and exception safety is the more interesting point here. If you'd want to only store plain pointers in your deque you have an exception-safety problem as in case of a thrown exception your strings wouldn't be deleted anymore. To circumvent this problem you'd need something like a smart-pointer(e.g.: std::unique_ptr), which would require C++11 move-semantics or a shared_ptr which would add additional overhead for ref-counting. The cleanest solution is to use C++11 move semantics in combination with plain strings. You could just move the buffer to the write function and further into the handler with the added benefits of no copying and exception safety.
Another point before talking about performance and copying is that you should measure if this is really a problem and that you are not bottlenecked by something different like network-I/O.